# Minecraft crashes with error "No OpenGL context found in the current thread"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I downloaded the Minecraft launcher and tried to download the latest update of Minecraft (1.7.4). The bar will fill up entirely at the bottom, then it will disappear, leaving me hanging, waiting for the darn thing to load, which it never did. I exited out of the launcher and opened it up again. Then, when I tried to load the 1.7.4 update, it crashes and leaves a long crash report.

The full crash report is below, but the important pieces of information are:

> org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
>   [...]
>   OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.

How can I diagnose and fix this?

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Daisy, daisy...

Time: 12/28/13 1:41 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at azi.ad(SourceFile:325)
    at azi.f(SourceFile:696)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:152)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at azi.ad(SourceFile:325)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at azi.f(SourceFile:696)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:152)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.4
    Operating System: Windows XP (x86) version 5.1
    Java Version: 1.7.0, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode, sharing), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 4705208 bytes (4 MB) / 26808320 bytes (25 MB) up to 518979584 bytes (494 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.7.4
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Comment: Can you include the crash report please?

Comment: Please add the report to your question by pressing the "edit" button near the bottom left corner of your question.

Comment: Okay, I did @Wipqozn

Comment: Come look @ElfSlice

Comment: @user65169 Oh, I don't think I'll actually be able to help you personally, but adding it into your question will make it easier for someone who actually knows about this to help you.  =]

Comment: Thanks for editing the report into your question! I've extracted out the important bits from the report to make them easily visible to people viewing the question. It looks like you're having an issue with your graphics card. Updating the drivers to your graphics card may fix the issue.